# How to get the maximum possible sum of values of the edges’ endpoints php

Tags: php, edges

The contents of this question have been removed due to a DMCA Takedown request by Codility Limited.

Comment: pls show what you have done/attempted (show your code)

Comment: I've no clue at all. Tried Making two arrays with swapping their value for edges like 2:1 2:3 and making the sum. but not getting any solution

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is no longer usefully answerable after it's entire content has been DMCA-ed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Simplets PHP solution for the Above question from the Codility test.

```
    <?php
    $A = [2,2,1,2];
    $B = [1,3,4,4];
    $w = [3,5,2,4,1];
    $N = 5;
    // $A = [1];
    // $B = [3];
    //  $A = [1,3];
    // $B = [2,4];


    function solution ($N, $A, $B){

        if(count($A) != count($B) || !is_int($N) )
        {
            return false;
        }

        $V = [];
        $vertextCount = [];
        foreach($A as $k=>$val){

            if(!isset($vertextCount[$val])){
                $vertextCount[$val] = 0;
            }
        
            $vertextCount[$val] += 1;
            
        }
        
        foreach($B as $k=>$val){
            if(!isset($vertextCount[$val])){
                $vertextCount[$val] = 0;
            }
        
            $vertextCount[$val] += 1;
        }

        if($vertextCount < $N)
        {
            $vertextCount[$N] = 0;
        }
        
        
        $VC = $vertextCount;
        $tn = $N;
        $wightArr = [];
        while(count($VC) > 0){
        
            $maxKey = current(array_keys($VC, max($VC)));
            $wightArr[$maxKey] = $tn;
            unset($VC[$maxKey]);
            $tn--;
        }
        $sum = 0;
        foreach($A as $k=>$val){
            $sum += $wightArr[$A[$k]] + $wightArr[$B[$k]];
            
        }
        return $sum;
    }
    echo $sum = solution($N, $A, $B);
```

NOTE:- Tested against the 3 given Examples in the test, Not sure about all the test cases.